# C++ program isn't right...unless I put cout in my loop?

Tags: c++, palindrome

You may recognise this from Project Euler. I'm trying to write a code to find the largest palindrome from multiplying three-digit numbers. There is cout << i << endl; in the for loop to indicate where in the process we are. If you run that code exactly as it is then I obtain the answer, but if I take out cout << i << endl; then I seem to get zero.

I don't exactly know what's going on, the code seems to work depending on whether I have cout included to indicate where I am...what?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool palindromecheck(int x);

int main() {
  int largest=0;

  for (int i = 999; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << i << endl;
    for (int j = 999; j > 0; j--) {
      if (palindromecheck(i*j) && i*j > largest) {
        largest = i*j;
      }
    }
  }

  cout << "The largest palindrome made from multiplying two 3-digit numbers is " << largest << endl;
}


bool palindromecheck(int x) {
  int z = x;
  int y;

  while (z != 0) {
    while (z%10 != 0) {
      z -= 1;
      y += 1;
    }

    while (z%10 == 0 && z != 0) {
      z /= 10;
      y *= 10;
    }
  }

  return x==y;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've got after you remove that line?

Comment: @JoeM: You can't mentally comment it out?

Comment: @FredLarson My thought was OP was accidentally removing something else in addition to that line.  Was hoping they would notice it when going to post the changed code.

Comment: @JoeM: I see what you're saying. I think the answers have likely identified the actual problem, though.

Answer (score 5):

The local variable `y` inside function `palindromecheck()` is not initialized. This makes the behaviour of your program unpredictable.

When the line `cout << i << endl;` is included it happens that `y` starts with a value that makes your program look like it is working. When it is not included, `y` is initialized with a a different value and it does not work any more.

In both cases, it just **looks** like it's working. In fact, the behavior of your program is undefined.

Initialize `y` properly before the outer loop (on its declaration).

Comment: Time to throw myself off a cliff. Thanks.

Comment: @AntiElephant: No need to do anything desperate. It's not like you're the first programmer to forget to initialize a variable. Just fix it and get on with life.

Answer (score 3):

The `y` variable doesn't have an initial value. That might lead to inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize y and that will make your code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, just a simplified version of function `palindromecheck()`:

```
bool palindromecheck(int x)
{
  int z = x;
  int y = 0;

  while (z != 0) {
    // Transfer the last digit of z to the end of y
    y = 10 * y + z % 10;
    z /= 10;
  }

  return x == y;
}
```

(proper initialization of `y` included)